# PHP remote procedure calling

Tags: php, xml-rpc, rpc, tunnel

I have two servers on PHP that need to communicate, calling remote methods of each other.  XML-RPC for PHP is not very good solution because it's very slow, and I can't call multiple methods in one request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [MultiRpc](http://code.google.com/p/multirpc/) - multiple methods calling in 1 request, by encrypted and compressed protocol.

Answer (score 1):

XML-RPC in PHP is pretty fast actually, if you use the built-in xmlrpc methods. It supports multiple method calls in a single request as well, using system.multiCall. The native multiCall is broken up to PHP 5.3.2 though. I've written an easy to use library for xmlrpc, called Ripcord, which allows you to very easily create servers and clients and works around most of the bugs in PHP's native xmlrpc methods. See http://ripcord.googlecode.com/

Comment: Ripcord uses PHPs [xmlrpc_decode](http://php.net/manual/de/function.xmlrpc-decode.php) which can not parse 64bit integers (i8)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for RipCord. I think it's a very good library. I just used it and could exec some rpc in just a hour or less.